# Machine Learning with Manipulate

Tags: machine-learning

My code pops up error, and it take lots of time before Mathematica finish this.
What's the problem here?

*Can anyone improve my code here?*

```
list1 = Table[i, {i, 3, x}];
list2 = Table[i^2, {i, 3, x}];
list3 = Table[2 i, {i, 3, x}];
Transpose[{list2, list3}] // FindFormula
Manipulate[
 Column@{p = 
    Predict[list2 -> list3, Method -> "NeuralNetwork", 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], p[625]}, {x, 20, 100}]
```

**Here is the one without Manipulate.**

```
   x = 1000;
list1 = Table[i, {i, 3, x}];
list2 = Table[i^2, {i, 3, x}];
list3 = Table[2 i, {i, 3, x}];
Transpose[{list2, list3}]//FindFormula
p = Predict[list2 -> list3, Method -> "NeuralNetwork", 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
p[4]
```

**I wanna set the value of "x" with `Manipulate`.**

Comment: "What's the problem here?" I get a loud beep and error message saying `Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {Table[i^2,{i,3,x}],Table[2 i,{i,3,x}]} cannot be transposed.` do you not get same message? What is `x` in the Table upper limit? You need some actual value there.

Comment: @Nasser, I tried to use manipulate  to set the value of x.

Comment: I see. But you are doing the list before that. You need to do it then inside Manipulate.

Comment: From your new code you just added, what is the purpose of `Transpose[{list2, list3}]`? It is not doing anything.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `list2` and `list3` are defined by simple functions `i^2` and `2 i`, so there is no need for a NN to predict the relationship, it is well known.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, I just wanna test the built-in Machine Learning of Mathematica.

Comment: @Nasser, how can I do it inside ```Manipulate```? I do not think by simply doing it inside Function ```Manipulate``` works here. If you have any  way to solve it, please write it in the answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanna test the built-in Machine Learning of Mathematica

I would use a more challenging problem to test the ML capabilities of WL. There are several good examples in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksOverview.html). I think this is what you are looking for

```
p = Predict[Thread[list2 -> list3], Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]
```

Rather than putting `x` in a `Manipulate`, try plotting the difference between the predicted and expected value for a given input.